# Cannot Render in Cycles - "No Render Output Node In Scene" error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I must have accidentally clicked on something because when I went to edit my model and tried rendering it, it won't render. It says:

"No Render Output Node In Scene"

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As others said, it seems you tried compositing nodes, but then deleted them. But, you probably forgot to uncheck "use nodes"!

If you "use nodes", you need to have an output node!

You could just disable this setting, and leave "compositing" enabled. It should work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turn off compositing in Post progressing tab in render settings.

[image]

You just created compositing nodes and deleted them.